# How to hide labels in last release of Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I do not find the set up to hide the labels in the latest Google Maps version. I use it on Internet Explorer / Mozilla Firefox / Google Chrome.

In the setting options I have:

- Share this map
- History
- Search settings

But none of these help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top left hand corner there are 3 horizontal bars in the search box, Click and you will see the menus.

Earth labels on off.

Took ages to find it. Also has the help and other menus :-)

Google you hid the Help